# Vulnerabilidades Shodan: Versiones de Apache distisntas en Shodan y en Debian

Tags: seguridad, apache2

Estaba comprobando las vulnerabilidades que muestra Shodan en el servidor en el que trabajo. Al ejecutar el comando correspondiente (shodan host XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA) las **vulnerabilidades que muestra (ver imagen abajo **marcado en azul**) están asociadas a la versión de Apache 2.4.38**.

Con idea de solventarlas actualizo la versión de Apache que tenía en mi *Debian 10*, a la que ofrece en los paquetes de Backports. Lo realizo y efectivamente **Apache cambia a la versión 2.4.41**  como se ve al principio de la imagen (**marcado en naranja**).

Sin embargo cuando ejecuto el comando de Shodan muestra el mismo resultado, y lo que es más extraño es que la versión que detecta es la antigua (**marcado en amarillo**).

¿Alguien sabe qué ocurre? ¿cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias de antemano; un saludo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]